# Symfony Twig: send a set parameter with a form submit request

Tags: symfony

I have a form in my twig, i want that by clicking on its submit button, another parameter (that i've set in the twig) get sent to the same action that handles the form : 
 this is the variable i've set

```
 {% set idprof = profil.id %}
```

I want to send it with the submit request : ( i know this code is false)

```
{{ form_widget(form.id),{'idprof': idprof} }}
```

and the action will look like this :

```
public function gestProfAction(Request $request, $idprof)
    {
}
```

I'm sorry i know this is a stupid question, but I'm still new in symfony, I couldn't find a solution by myself.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass it in the form start line

```
{{ form_start(form, {'action': path('idprof', { 'idprof': idprof })}) }}
```

Remember to add the annotation or yaml for the routing

```
/**
* @Route("/idprof/{idprof}", name="idprof")
*/
public function gestProfAction(Request $request, $idprof)
{
}
```

For reference:

- http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#rendering-the-form
- http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/action_method.html
- http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html#linking-to-pages

Comment: I got this error "Variable "idprof" does not exist in "???twig.html" ; But i've set 'idprof' in the twig  {% set idprof = profil.id %} !!

Comment: You really need that var? Try {{ form_start(form, {'action': path('idprof', { 'idprof': profil.id })}) }}

Comment: yup everything is about that var, i tried that code, it seems to be right, but i changed a little bit {{ form_widget(form, {'action': path('gestProf', { 'idprof': idprof })}) }} :gestProf is the route name of the action that handles the form

Comment: Instead of using the idprof var in the path() function, try passing  `profil.id` and see if it works

Comment: my mistake was that the code had to be inside a {% for %} block as the var set and the var profil.id where declared there, so when put it there it seems that it works now. thank you Renan :D

Comment: ooooh the submit button now doesn't send the request to the action!!! it just sends that var 'idprof' but when i write data in the inputs they are not sent

Comment: @Susan This problem is not related to your original question. Check the HTML source, if the path with the given idprof var is added to the "action" attribute of the form your original issue is solved.

Comment: i think there is no way to send a request and a var at the same time :(

Comment: I wanted to send both that var and the request to the action, but actually it sends only the var idprof